# CSS3 animation-fill-mode: forwards

Tags: jquery, animation, css

Just using Google Chrome at the moment.

I thought that adding `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` would persist the end state of an animation.

See [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/BYfDZ/14/).

Why isn't the image staying at -180 degrees?

EDIT:
I want the animation to be able to run again, with things as they are at the end of the last animation.  This is a simplified version of the problem - the actual problem rotates 15 degrees, and I want the image to be rotated a further 15 degrees on each run. If I don't remove the class the 2nd click of the button does not do anything.

CSS:

```
.flip180 {
    -webkit-animation-name: flip180;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flip180 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0); }
    to   { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg); }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="flipButton">Flip</button>

<img id="shape" src="http://media.creativebloq.futurecdn.net/sites/creativebloq.com/files/articles/article/2012/07/darth.jpg">​
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#flipButton').click(function() {
        $('#shape').addClass('flip180').on('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
            $('#shape').removeClass('flip180');
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: I just edited yours : http://jsfiddle.net/BYfDZ/16/ . If you want to stay at the end with 180, don't remove the flip180 class.

Comment: Thanks, but see edit to my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Check out mine : http://jsfiddle.net/BYfDZ/16/
```

My advice is not to remove the "flip180" class after you added to your class